# ASP.NET Core 3.1 OpenIDConnect, how to update claims without user logging out

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

Using `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and `OpenIDConnect`, I am able to Authenticate, and during the process flow, I add the users claims, e.g. the users roles granting access to resources.

If I alter the users "Roles" during runtime, I do not want the user to sign-out, but instead I want to enforce the token to be refreshed, and have the new claims/roles.

Currently I am using this `options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => { /* add claims if authenticated */}` to add the claims initially.

I have added middleware to detect if the user has a new "Role", and want to force the event to fire again.

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the content of the access token each time you refresh it and you can enable it by setting the UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh flag to true. See the documentation [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/).

The question is how much "lag" you can accept between the change in the database and until the access token is refreshed.

If you want to update the user in the client, then you must use one of the events in the AddCookie handler. The AddOpenIDConnect handler is ONLY involved when the user initially log in. After that, AddCookie is in charge and owns the user object (ClaimsPrincipal).

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions, and both are not ideal.

The first one does not work when you use Ajax calls. (I got CORS errors and found no way to allow the host; the preflight call failed.)

```cs
// middleware
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    
    if (userRolesHaveChanged) {

        context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl });
        return;
    }

    // the normal flow
    await next(context);
}
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XYZ/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8083%2FAuth%2FLogin%2FSignInOidc&response_type=id_token&/x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0'
> (redirected from 'https://localhost:8083/ PATH') from origin
> 'https://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

To overcome the CORS problem, I have come up with a HACK, by making use of the
Cookie expire time.

First configure OpenIdConnect to make use of the cookie expire time,
and then when the users roles have changed, simply delete the controlling cookie.

```cs
// startup
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions> (OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false; // Expire time
    options.SignInScheme = "hack";

    // SNIPPED CODE 

.AddCookie("hack", "hack", options =>
    {
        const int minute = 60;
        const int hour = minute * 60;
        const int day = hour * 24;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(day/2.0);
    })
```

Then within the Middleware

```cs
// middleware
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    if (userRolesHaveChanged) {    

            // force expire....
            // causes the next page load to indirectly call ChallengeAsync
            context.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.hack");

            // also possibly set some other controlling variable,
            // and deal with it, within the Ajax call
            // e.g.
            context.Response.Cookies.Append(
                "autoSignIn", 
                redirectUrl, 
                new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false }
            );
    }
```

The solution is terrible and clunky.